# GNUPG - stdin Decryption error

Tags: encryption, gnupg

I am using an Encryption method as mentioned below:

```
--homedir "C:\GnuPG" --batch --yes --encrypt --recipient a@a.com --default-key a@a.com --passphrase-fd 0 --no-verbose
```

It generates a.gpg file.

But when i decrypt this file on the stdin as mentioned below command:

```
gpg --output my.csv --decrypt a.gpg
```

Error:

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: decrypt_message failed: eof
```

Whats wrong with the Encryption command?

Comment: Works OK for me. I can't reproduce your error. Please post the entire command you use, and ensure that `C:\GnuPG` is where your `pubring.gpg` and `secring.gpg` reside.